# Objective c: How to only delete all file under a directory but keep the directory itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I found the code below to delete file in objective-c, but I want to only delete all files under directory of `Caches` and keep the directory `Caches` itself.

Could someone suggest the method to do that?

Thanks

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error: NULL]  == YES)
        NSLog (@"Remove successful");
else
        NSLog (@"Remove failed");
```

UPDATED

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error: NULL]  == YES)
    NSLog (@"Remove successful");
else
    NSLog (@"Remove failed");

[filemgr createDirectoryAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: How about re-create the Caches folder after deletion?

Comment: You could remove the directory and then recreate it, although you'd have to make sure you maintain the correct permissions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Loop through the files in that directory.

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:nil];
for (NSString *filename in fileArray)  {

    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but got error while compiling the program. `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8b8c0001)`

Comment: In which line it shows the error  ? , debug the code and say.

Comment: My mistake, the filename is just the name, have to append the directory to get the fullpath

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/"]];
//Load from File
NSFileManager *fileManage=  [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManage   removeItemAtPath:myPathDocs error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) removeDocuments
{
    NSString *docDir = // get documents directory
    NSString *cacheDir = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"cacheDir"];

    // check if cache dir exists

    // get all files in this directory
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: cacheDir error: nil];

    // remove
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [fileList count]; ++i)
    {
        NSString *fp =  [fileList objectAtIndex: i];
        NSString *remPath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: fp];
        [fm removeItemAtPath: remPath error: nil];
    }
}
```