# Clear image that is cached on logout

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios-simulator, cache-control

I have created an image in the cache as follows:

```
NSURL *cachesDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]; // iOS Caches directory

NSURL *profilePictureCacheURL = [cachesDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"FacebookProfilePicture.jpg"];

BOOL cachedToDisk = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[profilePictureCacheURL path] contents:newProfilePictureData attributes:nil];

NSLog(@"Wrote profile picture to disk cache: %d", cachedToDisk);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:newProfilePictureData];

UIImage *mediumImage = [image thumbnailImage:280 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
UIImage *smallRoundedImage = [image thumbnailImage:64 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:9 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];

NSData *mediumImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mediumImage, 0.5); // using JPEG for larger pictures
NSData *smallRoundedImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallRoundedImage);
```

What should I add to another method (for logout) to clear this image from the cache?

Tried this and it didn't work:

```
// Clear the cached profile and other images in cache 
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSString *cachesDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]    URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

// iOS Caches directory 
NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachesDirectoryURL error:nil]; 
for (NSString *filename in fileArray) 
{ 
  [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[cachesDirectoryURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL]; 
} –
```

Comment: Using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:error:]` given that you have the image paths. Do you only want to delete the images you cached or everything in the cache?

Comment: Thanks @yuk I edited the question to include the setting of the paths, I only need to clear the one cached image, but to know how to clear the entire directory of cached items would be good as well?

Comment: Clearing directory, just loop through files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530185/objective-c-how-to-only-delete-all-file-under-a-directory-but-keep-the-director

Comment: I tried this.but did not work the file is not removed
   // Clear the cached profile and other images in cache
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *cachesDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]; // iOS Caches directory
    NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachesDirectoryURL error:nil];
    for (NSString *filename in fileArray)  {
        
        [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[cachesDirectoryURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
    }

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Print out the directory strings and filenames, breakpoint in the for loop to see exactly what it's trying to delete? I can't really tell you what's wrong because it looks right.